# how to initialized array value's into another new array

Tags: iphone

I have array distanceListArray.. 5 km, 10 km, 15km, 20 km, 25 km.
distanceListArray is of appDelegate.class

distanceArray count is 5.

Now i do have another array.

which have list of events data ...

eventListArray is of DistanceClass

call eventListArray. for 5 km its displays 10 events, for 10 km its display 20 events.

Now i need to load data for each section from distanceListArray of eventListArray Into another new array.

All Arrays's are NSMutableArray.

I hope this makes ambiguity.

please help try to help me out.

Comment: Be a little careful with this: "I hope this makes ambiguity." ;) I'm actually not sure what you mean by the loading sections into other sections. Can you be a little clearer with what the data looks like, and the format you want to result in?

Comment: Actually i am doing searching option for my tableview.  here i displayed data depending on the sections i displayed event's..  Now i need to do searching for this context.

Comment: i section for tableview..i mean.. header title's

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  It's working, but I don't know where I will struck in my searching.

```
newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    for (EventInfo *string in [[appDelegate.distanceListArray objectAtIndex:i] eventListArray]) {
        NSLog(@"String is %@",string.event_Title);
        [newArray addObject:string];
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code... I had a problem... when objectAtIndex: counts goes to 1 ,2,3,4,5......  i value. incremented i Do not have for 2nd object eventListArray its empty... its gets me crash...  can any one help me out.

Comment: Yeah sure why dont you use `newArray = [appDelegate.distanceListArray mutableCopy];`? Please try using `newArray = [appDelegate.distanceListArray mutableCopy];` instead of your `for` loop. Hope this helps you.